# drupal 6 crashes apache running xampp

Tags: apache, drupal, crash

I am running drupal 6 on xampp 1.7.1.
PHP Version 5.2.9
The problem is that Apache crashes when I load a drupal 6 site.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.2.11.0
  Application Timestamp:    493f5d44
  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.2.9.9
  Fault Module Timestamp:   49a56925
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 00151f11
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033

I can run cron.php with no problems whatsoever.
Here is my code from index.php.

```
 require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);


$return = menu_execute_active_handler();



// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.

if (is_int($return)) {
  switch ($return) {
    case MENU_NOT_FOUND:

      drupal_not_found();
      break;
    case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
      drupal_access_denied();
      break;
    case MENU_SITE_OFFLINE:

      drupal_site_offline();
      break;

  }
}


/*
elseif (isset($return)) {
    echo $return;
  // Print any value (including an empty string) except NULL or undefined:
 print theme('page', $return);
}

drupal_page_footer();
*/
```

If I comment the last bit,the elseif and the footer part I get a white screen.
If I uncomment it Apache crashes.I have no idea what is happening.
I downloaded the live site to my localhost,changed the db_url from settings,and I got this.
Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you list down the modules used in the site?
Also try putting exit in init hook of all modules.

Can you run update.php properly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Then I upgraded my Apache installation (I was using xampp) and it was resolved.